# How do I pass additional parameters to the handlers in $.fn.hover()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The documentation of [jQuery's hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) shows only one method of using the function:

```
$('.myClass').hover(function () {
    console.log('on mouse over');
},
function () {
    console.log('on mouse out');
});
```

However, when you change these to named functions it doesn't work correctly, firing the named functions upon page load (or as soon as you paste it into your console):

```
function onMouseOver() {
    console.log('on mouse over');
}

function onMouseOut()
    console.log('on mouse out');
}

$('.myClass').hover(onMouseOver(), onMouseOut());
```

Changing the last line to:

```
$('myClass').hover(onMouseOver, onMouseOut);
```

works as expected (firing on the event), but doesn't allow me to pass anything to the named functions. Is there any way to allow me to pass a variable to the functions?

Comment: By using ``onMouseOver()`` in ``$('.myClass').hover(onMouseOver(), onMouseOut());`` you are actually invoking each of the functions, instead of just passing them to hover as callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you need to use anonymous functions for this:

```
$('myClass').hover(function( e ) {
    onMouseOver( param1, param2... );
}, function( e ) {
    onMouseOut( param1, param2... );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables into the named functions by calling it like so:

```
$('.myClass').hover(function() {
    onMouseOver(arg);
}, function() {
    onMouseOut(arg);
});
```

That's the only way to pass arguments, parameters into the named functions from that event.

Answer (score 1):

The `hover` sugar method isn't really meant for complex scenarios.

In your case it would probably be better to use `.on('mouseenter')` and `on('mouseleave')` so that you can pass additional `event` data to each method, like

```
$('.myClass').on('mouseenter', {param1: val1}, onMouseOver).on('mouseleave', {param2: val2}, onMouseOut);
```

Then within your handlers you can access those params like so:

```
function onMouseOver(e) {
    console.log(e.data.param1);
}

function onMouseOut(e) {
    console.log(e.data.param2);
}
```

That's the sort of *jQuery way* to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with function references vs. function invocation.  Adding the "()" invokes the function (which in this case you'd be doing at binding time...effectively binding the result of the function rather than the function itself.

To pass arguments the simplest option would be to wrap the named function in an anonymous function (as @antyrat just posted).

And also no, this is not a quirk of hover, this is standard JavaScript (and most any other language that has first class functions).

Answer (score 0):

As several others have noted, you'll have to use *currying* or *binding* to pass values to the functions.  In the example where you wrote this:

```
$('.myClass').hover(onMouseOver(), onMouseOut());
```

you're actually calling the onMouseOver() and onMouseOut() methods immediately on that line, and *not* when the mouse actually moves over or out of the element; what you wrote is equivalent to writing this:

```
var mouseOverResult = onMouseOver();
var mouseOutResult = onMouseOut();
$('.myClass').hover(mouseOverResult, mouseOutResult);
```

That's definitely not what you want.

jQuery can only understand functions that are of the form `function(event)`, so if you want more parameters, or other parameters, you'll have to use currying to get them in there.  Currying (named for the math professor who devised the concept) can be thought of as creating a new function where the values you want to pass are 'pre-bound' inside it.

So let's say you have a variable `foo` that you'd like to pass into your `onMouseOver` handler, like this:

```
function onMouseOver(foo) {
    ...
}

...

var foo = "Hello, World";

$('myClass').hover(...);
```

To be able to pass that value, you need another function that wraps up that `foo` and that `onMouseOver` with a function signature that jQuery can use.  You do it like this:

```
function onMouseOver(foo) {
    ...
}

...

var foo = "Hello, World";

var curriedOnMouseOver = function(event) {
    onMouseOver(foo);
};

$('myClass').hover(curriedOnMouseOver);
```

As several others have suggested, you can avoid the extra variable declaration by creating the curried closure inside the `hover()` call:

```
function onMouseOver(foo) {
    ...
}

...

var foo = "Hello, World";

$('myClass').hover(function(event) {
    onMouseOver(foo);
});
```

This example above also shows how you would pass the event to your function as well, by simply adding more parameters to it:

```
function onMouseOver(event, foo, bar) {
    ...
}

...

var foo = "Hello, World";
var bar = "Goodbye, World";

$('myClass').hover(function(event) {
    onMouseOver(event, foo, bar);
});
```

JavaScript's functions --- or **closures** --- are incredibly powerful tools, and it would be worth your while to learn some of the things you can do with them, like these examples.